# How to get request url using spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Actually i'm preparing Sending Activation mail to User Account and It is working but when he Accept the  mail Request will redirect to our application with secure encrypt key...

In this way i'm preparing spring templete..

```
<bean id="activateAccountTemplate" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
    <property name="subject" value="Account activation" />
    <property name="text">
        <value>
        <![CDATA[
            <html><body><p>Dear %s</p><p>Click <a href="http://localhost:8080/EClass/home?a=%s">here</a> to activate your account.</p></body></html>
        ]]>
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In User mail message like..

```
    Dear Narasimham

Click *here* to activate your account.
```

So when we click Activation mail link in url coming like this..

```
http://localhost:8080/EClass/home?a=tdpTA3Dz8DYSI+9F/DpMxmxGD/a1Kl+3oYqXc1NNH0U=
```

So how to write controller getting this request parameter and how to decrypt this key?

Actually i'm writing controller using `@RequestMapping(value="home", method=RequestMethod.GET)` ambiguity Exception comming because i'm using `value="home"` in two Controller classes..

So how to write Controller using value `"home"` (hear home mean home .jsp)..

Please suggest me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use separate values for @RequestMapping. You are getting Ambiguity exception because you have two mappings with value="home".

Comment: Please provide sample code..hear @RequestMapping(value="home", params = "a") wirte...Exception coming... java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'LOGIN' available as request attribute

Comment: Have you specified method=RequestMethod.GET in @RequestMapping? It will be helpful to resolve the issue if you can provide your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have RequestMapping with duplicate configuration. You can qualify it using params also if the params differ.

```
@RequestMapping(value="home", params = "a")
```

Read more about RequestMapping to understand the usage.

Comment: Exception : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'LOGIN' available as request attribute